# Covering the root view with another immediately upon launch or resume

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to build a security app that prompts the user to enter a passcode before allowing access to the application.  This is done on the first launch or when the application is resumed.

Right now, I'm using a view controller, `PasscodeViewController`, which is presented modally on application launch or resume, i.e., in the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if (!self.passcodeViewController.view.window)
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.passcodeViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

The problem is that the main view controller's view is flashed momentarily before the `PasscodeViewController` is presented.  This is a security risk because the user can quickly get a glimpse of the data before being asked to enter a passcode.

How do you solve this?  How do programs like DotLockData, and other security programs, implement such a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems it would be better to do that sort of thing on suspend rather than resume. Perhaps in `applicationWillResignActive`